# Parallel.ForEach is faster than regular foreach?

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, foreach, parallel-processing, iteration

I wonder if i change all my regular ForEach to Parallel.ForEach, will speed up all my iterations or it depends on the situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on how your processing is bound.  If it is bound by a single CPU thread and you have multiples available, then yes it will be faster.  If your code is waiting for the database, then spawning multiple copies may get a slight increase if the database supports good parallel operations.

The biggest thing to consider is will your code work correctly if split between threads, or do you have race-conditions that could cause problems?

Answer (score 3):

Depends on the situation.  Most instances of for-each do not perform computationally expensive actions or blocking actions, so the overhead of creating tasks and assigning threads is too much to be worth it.

Parallelism isn't the holy grail of performance and not all problems can be parallelised to improve performance.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on the situation.  Parallel for each will run multiple iterations concurrently if it can, but there are times when it can such as on a single processor machine.

You have to be careful though that the task you are trying to speed up shouldn't be run serially.  You still have to worry about concurrency conditions, like multiple threads writing to the same list etc., so it's not always the best idea to use it.

Answer (score 1):

It would absolutely depend on the situation, there's a lot of overhead involved in doing the threading operations and such, so something like:

```
foreach(char c in alphabet)
{
  myStr += c;
}
```

Would not benefit from parallelizing (amongst other issues).  Where as something like:

```
foreach(File f in myLargeLogFiles)
{
   LogFileProcessor p = new LogFileProcess();
   p.ProcessLogFile(f);
}
```

Could very well benefit from parallelizing.  It comes down to how heavy the work-load inside the loop is; is the benefit from the parallelism greater than that of the overhead of creating the threads, synchronization of the threads, etc.

Comment: so there is always an additional cost on using Parallel.ForEach, I must then measure if the additional cost really helps or not on every case?.

Comment: Yes, there's always a cost; I don't know that you need to measure it every time.  Just understanding that there are trade-offs is the point, and using that information to make your decision.  Do you measure the time difference between using a `StringBuilder` vs. doing a simple string concatenation?